# What sort of magic can I add to this function to make it refresh every 5 mins?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the function that I am working with:

```
   $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=starcraft&limit=18&&type=top&callback=?", function (data) {
    var temp = "";

    $.each(data.streams, function (index, item) {
        temp = temp + "<li><a target='iframe1' href='http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + item.channel.name + "'>" + item.channel.display_name + "</a></li>";

        });
    $("#list ul ").html(temp);
});
```

do I use setInterval() to make this function reload lets say every 5 mins?

Thank you!

Comment: *"do I use setInterval() to make this function reload lets say every 5 mins?"* Yep. Or `setTimeout`. You're welcome!

Comment: Hey SamK, I see you've asked a few questions already all in the form of "how can I do xyz?". It helps (and is appreciated) on StackOverflow if you include some more info, things you've tried and researched, and be specific about where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

```
var refresh = function() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=starcraft&limit=18&&type=top&callback=?", function (data) {
        var temp = "";

        $.each(data.streams, function (index, item) {
            temp = temp + "<li><a target='iframe1' href='http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + item.channel.name + "'>" + item.channel.display_name + "</a></li>";
        });

        $("#list ul ").html(temp);
   });

};

setInterval(refresh, 5 * 60 * 1000); // 5 minutes * 60 secs * 1000 ms
```

So basically, you put your code in function and use setInterval like this:

```
setInterval( function, time )
```

You can also do it with anonymous function:

```
setInterval(function() {
    somecode
}, 300000);
```

If you want to clear the interval after certain amount of time u can do:

```
var interval = setInterval( function, time );

setTimeout(function(){ 
   clearInterval(interval); 
}, 9 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: 5 minutes = 300,000, setInterval accepts ms not seconds

Answer (score -2):

> do I use setInterval() to make this function reload lets say every 5 mins?

No, you don't. But you definitely could.

Comment: I don't think it was meant to be taken literally.